# Can Custom Authentication be made in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use a 6 digit code to log-in a user.
The code is available for 20 seconds and is unique to every user.

Briefly explained:

- User is already logged in on a mobile app
- User press the button "Get Unique Code"
- Then, user enter the code on a WebPage on his PC
- If the code is correct, show data for that user

What am I asking is if there is way to properly authenticate the user who introduces that code correctly given that I have the userID and all the informations about the user?

I can try and "fake log-in" (display all the information for that user when the code is correct) but there are some issues with this and I would like to avoid it.

I am using Firebase Authentication and Firebase Firestore. JavaScript is used for Web.

Comment: You can implement any authentication scheme you want by creating a custom provider for Firebase Authentication. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth?hl=en and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can implement any authentication scheme you want by creating a custom provider for Firebase Authentication.

See [Authenticate with Firebase in JavaScript Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) and [Creating Custom Tokens with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

In this flow you:

1. Sign in the users yourself.
2. Create a custom token for those users in a trusted environment, such as a server you control, or Cloud Functions.
3. Pass that custom token to Firebase Authentication, which can then use it to identify the user, and secure access to Firestore, Storage, and Realtime Database.